# jQuery not animating back up

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I have a box that should fade in and move up when clicked, but instead, it just stays down. The fading works...

Thanks for your help !

```js
var fadeInDown = function (element, duration, easing) {
  element.css({
    opacity: '0',
    webkitTransform: 'translateY(100%)',
    transform: 'translateY(100%)',
  })
  .animate({
    opacity: '1',
    webkitTransform: 'translateY(0%)',
    transform: 'translateY(0%)',
  }, duration, easing);
};

$('.box').click(function () {
  fadeInDown($('.box'), 400, 'swing');
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: When I say the fading works, the sliding doesn't, and that's the main focus of this animation.

Comment: Why not use `$(".box").slideUp().fadeOut()` ?  (or slideDown / fadeIn depending on your requirement, which is a little contradictory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's animate doesn't support css transforms like this. You'd need to introduce a step function, to animate it. This should be something close to what you're looking for:

```js
var fadeInDown = function (element, duration, easing) {
  element.css({
    opacity: '0',
    webkitTransform: 'translateY(0%)',
    transform: 'translateY(0%)',
  })
  .animate({
    opacity: '1'
  }, {
    duration: duration,
    step: function(now, fx) {
      var step = 100*now;
      $(this).css({
        webkitTransform: 'translateY(' + step + '%)',
        transform: 'translateY(' + step + '%)'
      });
    }
  }, easing);
};

$('.box').click(function () {
  fadeInDown($('.box'), 400, 'swing');
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="box"></div>
```

Also, take a look at [this question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5462275/animate-element-transform-rotate), which may give you some additional help.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help !!